# How to remove line break from CSV output

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to add a new column in my csv file to add '1' in a new column if the 'Description' column contains a text string. Looks like the code works but write.csv is messing up the output file by adding line breaks to 'Description' column

I am new to R and have tried a couple of things including using
library(stringr)

```
data1 = str_replace_all(data1, "[\r\n]" , "")
```

however it gets stuck!

```
data = read_excel("database.xlsx")
data1 = sqldf(c("alter table data add newcolumn numeric","select * from data"))
data1 = sqldf(c("update data1 set newcolumn = case when Description LIKE '%pyramidlike%' then 1 else 0
        end", "select * from data1"))
write.csv(data1, "data1.csv")
```

Comment: What does "it gets stuck" mean?

Comment: Means..there is no output. I just see the red stop icon and no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include sample data to make it a reproducible example. But nevertheless there are simpler ways of achieving what you want to do, and I will use a sample dataste (`iris`):

```
library(tidyverse)

# will use the IRIS dataset instead of your XLSX, adjust as needed.
data(iris)
new_iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(
    flag = ifelse(Species == "setosa", 1, 0)  # add a new column
  )
```

Just to make it clear what happened, let's look at the structure of the dataframes:

```
> str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> str(new_iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ flag        : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Then just write the dataframe to a CSV:

```
# I am using the tidyverse version of the function
write_csv(
  new_iris,
  path = "/path/to/output.csv"
)
```

For this particular case, there is no gain on using `sqldf()` to manipulate de dataset. Usually I use that when I am making changes directly in a database.

HTH

Comment: Thank you. In your data how do I filter all rows which 'contain' the text string 'sentosa'. I am not looking for ==

Comment: I mean mutate when the column 'contains' the text string 'setosa' (In SQL, I would write LIKE '%setosa%'

Comment: Check the `str_detect()` function (https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_detect.html) or one of the base R regex functions (see: https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)